# How To Use Plorly When I Use groupby in which i used Value_counts ( Pandas Lib )

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I Want To Visualize How Many Each Rate In Each Category Type, So I Used

```
q2 = df.groupby(['Category'])['Rating'].value_counts()
```

To Group The Data as I Need ( It Works Fine As I Need ), But When I Use

```
px.bar( q2, x = 'Category', y = 'Rating' )
```

I get " 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts' " Error, So What Can I Do It To Visualize This Groupby Value_counts Data?

**Data Link: https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps**

Answer (score 0):

So DataFrameGroupBy Object doesnt have value_counts but it does have sum

```
q2 = df.groupby(['Category', 'Rating'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Link to [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: It will sum all the rating for each app, but what i need is for example : facebook have 5 rating in 1 star, 4 rating in 5 stars, 3 rating in 2 stars and so on with each app

Comment: I just updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. I hope I can drop a photo for butter understanding

Comment: Yeah, just update the question